# async.each not iterating when using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I am trying to run an asynchronous loop `async.each` over an array of objects. 
On each object in the array, I am trying to run two functions sequentially (using `promises`). The problem is that `async.each` only runs for the first keyword.

In the following code, `getKeywords` loads some keywords from a file, then returns an array of keyword objects. Each keyword object is put into `searchKeyword` that makes a search. The search result is then put into a database using `InsertSearchResults`.

In my mind, each keyword should be processed in parallel and the search and insert functions are linked.

```
getKeywords(keys).then(function(keywords) {
    async.each(keywords, function(keywordObject, callback) {
        searchKeyword(keywordObject).then(function(searchResults) {
            return insertSearchResults(searchResults, db, collections);
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log("here");
            callback();
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: can you try calling the optional callback that captures `err` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only using `.then()` callbacks so you handle success.

But you should also add some `.catch()` callbacks to handle errors.

Most likely you get errors that are not handled and nothing happens.

For example:

```
            // ...
        }).then( function(result) {
            console.log("here");
            callback();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error:', error);
            callback(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that that I made an error in the getKeywords function.
I was reading from a file, then iterating through each line by using a for loop and pushing the result to an array. This array was then returned by the function.

async.each was working perfectly but was only ever receiving an array of length 1 to iterate over.

I fixed this problem by changing the for loop to an async.each loop

```
function getKeywords(keywordsFilename){
    //get keywords from the file
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        var keywords = [];
        fs.readFile(keywordsFilename, function read(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            content = data.toString();
            var lines = content.split("\n");
            async.each(lines, function(line, callback) {
                if (line[0] === "#" || line == "") {
                    callback();
                }
                else {
                    keywords.push(extractKeyword(line));
                    callback();
                }
            }, function (err) {
                resolve(keywords);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Writing the problem out helped, let me know if I should delete the question.

Thanks for your help Mukesh Sharma and rsp.